# Using JavaScript to hide a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Hiding
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script> src="scripts/hide.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div id ="hideme">
                <h1 class="type">strongbad_email.exe</h1>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
@keyframes typing { from { width: 0; } }
@keyframes blink-caret { 50% { border-color: transparent; } }

h1.type {   
    font: bold 100% Consolas;
    border-right: .1em solid;
    width: 19ch;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-left:5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: typing 3s steps(30, end), 
               blink-caret .5s;
}
```

JS

```
function hid() {
  document.getElementById("#hideme").style.display = "none";
}
setTimeout("hid()", 5000)
```

After the typing animation the text will remain on screen.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `document.getElementById("#hideme")` should be `document.getElementById("hideme")` (no `#`). Look in your console, please. (Unless you really have `<script> src`, in which case you also need to take out `>`.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your JavaScript. Try this instead:

```
function hid() {
  document.getElementById("hideme").style.display = "none";
}
setTimeout(hid, 5000)
```

When using [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), you don't need to specify the CSS ID selector.

You'll also simply want to just pass the function name into `setTimeout`, rather than a string.

Comment: funny thing is I test it without the # didn't work and thought I needed the # sign and why I end up posting it with that sign.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout's first argument should be a function name or an anonymous function:

function name:

```
 setTimeout(hid, 5000);
```

anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    hid();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: “Function name or anonymous function” is a strange distinction. It just has to be any function value… or a string, which, despite being bad practice, will work.

Comment: Interesting. I've never used a string, and have never seen a reference that mentioned string as accepted argument value. Why is it odd distinction? Those are only two possibilities for that argument that I was aware of.

Comment: It’s an odd distinction because it’s like saying “you can pass a variable name or an expression to `console.log`”. Variable names can be expressions too.

Comment: Id rather be specific than vague... just saying function value doesn't really help the uninformed...